# Apache Camel: how to do an XA Transactional Manager in a route with an FTP-endpoint and database write access in it?

Tags: java, apache-camel, transactional

This is the route:

```
from(jms:queue:xxx)
...
.process(_write_in_db_)
...
.to(ftp:yyy)
```

I think I need a global **XA Transactional Manager** that covers the whole route and commits the changes in DB and Queue only after global commit.

Unfortunatly I didn't found any examples for that case and would appriciate if anybody could say how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a excellent example @ https://github.com/FuseByExample/esb-transactions . I have personally used this example as starting point and it works perfectly.

> In studying this example you will learn:
>
> How to set up an XA-aware DataSource
>
> How to configure a JPA persistence unit
>
> How to leverage Fuse ESB's JTA and JPA support in your routes
>
> How to configure a JMS component to support XA
>
> How to define a transactional route
>
> How to configure a ResourceManager that can recover XA transactions after a crash

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it out.

Comment: Please do consider accepting the answer if it works out for you :)